# difference between null vs white space?

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose if i create a table with primary key
I can't insert null and duplicate values.
But i can insert white spaces.

eg:
insert into table_name values('         ');

then what is the difference between null and white space 
how does primary key works??

Comment: Your question would make slightly more sense in Standard SQL (which Oracle does **not** comply with). In Standard SQL, an empty string (a string with 0 characters) is still a value, it is not the same as NULL. Even then - you could use it as a "placeholder" - but not in a primary key. It, or a single space in Oracle, is often used in place of NULL if a column is constrained to NOT NULL (but not to PRIMARY KEY). Of course, if people do use single space to substitute for NULL, they are just working around a constraint. (continued below)

Comment: Either the NOT NULL constraint serves a legitimate purpose, in which case the people who work around it by inserting a single space should be found and fired, or the NOT NULL constraint serves no valid purpose, in which case it should be dropped. Either way this kind of approach makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

White spaces are strings, and you will not be able to insert two rows with primary keys having the same number of whites spaces.
A field with a NULL value is a field with no value. It is very important to understand that a NULL value is different than a zero value or a field that contains spaces, spaces are considered as values because they are strings (and sql can't tell what the value of a string means to the user per se), but a NULL signifies a missing value, and hence has no value associated with it.
If you find yourself having to insert white spaces, reconsider your database schema design.
More about [primary keys](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp)

Answer (score 1):

White spaces are string like enter, tab etc. But Null is like blank. Text Nulll is also white space.

Answer (score 0):

**Primary Key** : It is a constraint which means null values aren't allowed and repeated values are also not allowed in that column.

White space is considered as character, So white space is char like others a,b etc. so that's why it allows to enter it. Where NULL is actual nothing.

table if you want to